# Rendering a component only after API request is finished React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, react-hooks

I'm getting an error when my chart component renders due to its initial state which is an empty array before the API response. It would say something like `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` which is due to the fact that when the component loads, its initial state is, well... an empty array. So I'd like to know if there's a way to make the component render only after the API response is received.

Here is the parent component:

```
function InformationPage({
    match: {
        params: { symbol },
    },
}) {

    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]); {/*Declaring state*/}

useEffect(() => {  {/*Fetching API response here to set state*/}
    axios
        .get(
            `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=${symbol}&resolution=15&from=1572651390&to=1602623478&token=xxxxxxxxx`
        )
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setChartData(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, [symbol]);

return (
    
        <Grid item container xs={12} sm={12} md={6} lg={8}>
            {chartData && <QuoteChart chartData={chartData} iex={iex} />}
        </Grid>
    
   );
}
export Default InformationPage;
```

Here is the child chart component, basically when I do the fetch request from axios it returns an array that will get mapped in the `chartRender` object. I just need to find a way to render the component only AFTER the api request from axios is finished as to not have an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function QuoteChart(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { chartData } = props;

    const chartRender = chartData.map((chartConfig) => ({
        x: new Date(chartConfig?.t),
        y: [chartConfig?.o, chartConfig?.h, chartConfig?.l, chartConfig?.c],
    }));

    // const chartDataLog = console.log(chartData);
    const config = {
        series: [
            {
                data: [{ chartRender }],
            },
        ],
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** According to [Finnhub API](https://finnhub.io/docs/api#stock-candles) it's **an object** that you receive from the API, **not an array**. This means that `charData.length` in my previous answer will never be evaluated to `true` and the child component `QuoteChart` will never get rendered.

I'd suggest the following changes. In your parent component, make `charData = null` initially:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);
```

When the API has returned a response and `chartData` has been assigned a value your child component can be rendered:

```
{chartData && <QuoteChart chartData={chartData} iex={iex} />}
```

The chart you want to render in the child component expects the following input: `[{ x: date, y: [O,H,L,C] }]`. Because `map()` can only be called on arrays and `chartData` is not one, you should navigate to one of the arrays inside the said object, e.g. `chartData.t`:

```
const chartRender = chartData.t.map((timestamp, index) => ({
    x: new Date(timestamp),
    y: [chartData.o[index], chartData.h[index], chartData.l[index], chartData.c[index]],
}));
```

Finally, `series.data` expects an array, you don't need to additionally wrap it in an object. So this should work:

```
const config = {
    series: [{
        data: chartRender
    }]
};
```

---

You initialize `chartData` with an empty array, therefore your condition should look like this:

```
{chartData.length && <QuoteChart chartData={chartData} iex={iex} />}
```

If you expect the API to return an empty list, I'd recommend to set an `undefined` or `null` as the initial value of `chartData`:

```
const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);
```

In this case you can keep your condition as is.

Comment: I used `chartData.length` but when I console.log `chartData` from the child component, nothing shows up. I stopped getting errors but the component didn't render either.

Comment: @Pacholoamit What's the output of `console.log(res.data);` when you get a response from the API?

Comment: I'll set up a codepen so you can help me take a look. This is really confusing me. I'll comment it here in a few mins. Is there any way I can chat with you, if that's ok? I'm a female programmer and I'd appreciate it if I could have someone to go to if I'm having trouble. But if you don't prefer it that way then answering this question is fine. I'll set up the codepen from my repository now.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, hope it helps. It's always a good idea to have a link to Codepen.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-ramanujan-fnmyg?file=/src/components/QuoteChart.js) In codesandbox it says `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` however in my localhost it says `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Please provide [Open, High, Low and Close] values in valid format. Read more https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/#candlestick` I did a console.log and everything is rendering fine in terms of output of the map function but I get an apexchart error saying that the format isn't proper. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Pacholoamit The API responds with `{s: "no_data"}`, where s is the "Status of the response", according to the Finnhub API. This is because the `symbol` prop is `undefined`. If you navigate to a different route where the symbol is initialized with a value, e.g. https://fnmyg.csb.app/symbol/AAPL then you can see the chart. Make sure to change the chart config (the QuoteChart component) with `const confic = series: [{ data: chartRender }], ...`

Comment: HOAH! WOAAAAAHHH!!! It finally rendered. IT TURNS OUT that the main culprit was the DAMN BRACKETS! when I removed the curly brackets and the array brackets then it worked. I was like WHAT THE HECK! THESE DAMN BRACKETS. Thanks man, I owe you big time. I've been bashing my head trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken you can simply use async/await for your problem. So change the useEffect line to

```
useEffect(async () => {  {/*Fetching API response here to set state*/}
```

and then

```
 await axios
    .get(
        `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=${symbol}&resolution=15&from=1572651390&to=1602623478&token=xxxxxxxxx`
    )
```

Then your application should wait for the axios to finish fetching

Comment: You cannot pass an async function to `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would require a simple small change to your code:

```
 {chartData.length && <QuoteChart chartData={chartData} iex={iex} />}
```

After researching finnhub - I see that the response is not an array.
I tested this url:

```
https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=AAPL&resolution=15&from=1572651390&to=1602623478&token=
```

The response is an object with a "c" property.
Your code should be modified accordingly.
For the above link example:

```
setChartData(res.data.c);
```

Comment: I used chartData.length but when I console.log chartData from the child component, nothing shows up. I stopped getting errors but the component didn't render either.

Comment: if the child component renders nothing it means chartData.length is false - which means it's either en empty array, an object or a number...
Are you sure chartData is an array?

Comment: Here's what I get when i console.log the [api response](https://imgur.com/a/s61yMvW) as is.

Comment: Basically you should check res.data.s for the status - it's either "ok" or "no_data". Then you should use the data that interests you. You should read more about finnhub's api:
https://finnhub.io/docs/api#stock-candles.

Comment: it's apex chart, the library that I'm using. Finnhub is 100% working all the time and I'm sure as you tested. The api returns o, h, l, and c arrays. That's why I just did res.data because I would be accessing the o, h, l and, c arrays in the chart component but on initial render it keeps saying the error message 'Cannot read property[0] of undefined.' I just basically need the chart to render once the api request is complete so I can pass the o, h, l, and c arrays to a map function in the child component that is responsible for the data in the chart. Thanks for helping out a junior dev.

Comment: Right. Now i see you are right. In that case, just add a loading at the begeining and set it to true. Pass it to the chart. If loading - render a loader. Once api request comes back, set loading to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your axios call in an async function and `wait` there

```
useEffect(() => {  {/*Fetching API response here to set state*/}
    
   const getInfo = async () => {
       await res = axios
        .get(
            `https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/candle?symbol=${symbol}&resolution=15&from=1572651390&to=1602623478&token=xxxxxxxxx`
        )
        console.log(res.data);
        setChartData(res.data);
   }

   getInfo()
}, [symbol]);
```

Comment: useEffect will run after mount, how does that help

Comment: or maybe you intentionally skipped the part of checking before rendering component